# StarCraft2: MULE - can he work on one mineral patch with another SCV in parallel?

Tags: starcraft-2

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Calldown:_MULE

> Also, MULEs can mine over other SCVs

What this means? Does it mean that MULE and SCV can work on one mineral patch in the same time?

Thanks.

P.S. I've tried to look on that during game, but can' figure out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that's precisely what it means - a mule can mine a mineral patch which is already being mined by 3 SCVs (which is the maximum number of SCVs on a single patch). Consequently, mules can increase the mineral income even for expansions already completely saturated (24 SCVs on minerals).

Two mules can't mine from the same patch, by the way.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that fact, just today (1 month in game) discovered that :) Awesome!

Comment: SCVs can also repair mechanical structures.  So if you have a Thor on the battlefield stranded you can drop a Mule there to repair it.  This is a common practice among pros

Comment: @webnet I'm actually surprised I don't see that more, to be honest.

Comment: In the campaign, you can also use M.U.L.E.s to retrieve research artifacts.  This is most useful in Supernova, where after the fire has finished burning over an area, you can scan (if you have the Orbital Command Center) where an artifact is and then send a M.U.L.E. to pick it up.

Comment: What kind of artifact you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

To maximize your MULES you should make sure to place it on the closer patches to the CC and queu it to gather on the same patch.

Comment: Actually I have heard recently that if you put them on the close patch, the MULE will time-out before it can return the last trip, throwing away 5 minerals. Putting the MULE on the far patch will yield exactly the same amount of return but without the waste. Therefore it has been advised to put MULEs on far patches. Sorry I don't have a reference for this, and I haven't actually tested it.